# How to add a filter to magento navigation bar for a custom collection

Tags: magento, filtering, magento-1.6

I've got a page within my magento shop in where I list a collection of products. I joined the product collection with a custom table where some additional attributes are stored.

In the left column (navigation layer) the filters are shown where a selection can be made for a specific manufacturer or a specific category. Now I want to add my own filter on one of the fields from my custom table so that only the fields with a certain (non-negative) value for one of the added attributes will be shown when the filter is selected by the user.

When I try to find information on filters I often see people referring to the product attributes in the backend, however I doubt if it will apply here since it is not a product attribute in the sense of eav but one from my custom table (that is joined on sku). I am looking for an example or strategy on how I can add a filter based on a property in my joined collection.

Comment: You might want to take another look at the problem you are trying to solve using Product Attributes.